How to speed up interpolation in dask
I have a piece of data code that performs interpolation on a large number of arrays.
This is extremely quick with numpy, but:

The data the code will work with in reality will often not fit in memory
The tasks are embarrassingly parallel

So I would like to use dask/xarray to speed the process up and allow the tasks to be distributed.
However the speed of performing the same task with Dask is prohibitively slow.
Below is an example code that shows the difference in performing the interpolation on dask arrays vs numpy arrays:
import timeit

import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from dask.distributed import Client


client = Client(processes=False, threads_per_worker=1, n_workers=10, memory_limit="2GB")


n_points = 1500


x = np.linspace(0, 10, n_points)
y = np.sin(x)
xp = np.linspace(0, 10, n_points)


x_da = da.from_array(x, chunks="auto")
y_da = da.from_array(y, chunks="auto")
xp_da = da.from_array(xp, chunks="auto")


n_repeats = 50000


numpy_time = timeit.timeit(
    stmt="np.interp(xp, x, y)",
    setup="import numpy as np; x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1500); y = np.sin(x); xp = np.linspace(0, 10, 1500)",
    number=n_repeats,
)


# Timing np.interp with Dask arrays
def dask_interpolation():
    interpolated = da.map_blocks(np.interp, xp_da, x_da, y_da, dtype=float)
    interpolated.compute()


xarray_time = timeit.timeit(
    stmt="dask_interpolation()",
    setup="from __main__ import dask_interpolation",
    number=n_repeats,
)

# Print the timings
print(
    f"np.interp with numpy arrays: {numpy_time:.6f} seconds for {n_repeats} repetitions"
)
print(
    f"np.interp with Dask arrays: {xarray_time:.6f} seconds for {n_repeats} repetitions"
)

# Shutdown Dask client
client.shutdown()

which gives:
np.interp with numpy arrays: 0.264898 seconds for 50000 repetitions
np.interp with Dask arrays: 242.829727 seconds for 50000 repetitions

Can anyone suggest if and how it is possible to speed the Dask interpolation up?

Correct me if I am wrong : you run a distributed process of 10 processes using multiple computing nodes since memory is a bottleneck. However, it is not clear on what you run this and how many processes there is per machine. This is pretty critical for performance. For example, data certainly need to be tranfered from one computing node to another so the interconnect/network can be a significant bottleneck regarding the target platform (eg. a 1 Gbit network has a throughput >1000x lower than server DDR5 DRAMs -- a similar thing is true for the interconnect latency vs DRAM latency).

You are comparing speed of computation that takes milliseconds if not less to finish with Numpy, and the equivalent with Dask. Just the scheduling time of the task is greater than that. If you code is embarrassingly parallel, and your tasks last more than a second or so, then Dask will become efficient.
